# DisplayStateBehavior not initially applying state transition in listbox item template

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, expression-blend, visualstatemanager

I have a listbox item template that contains visual states.  I have DisplayStateBehaviors that set the states to either the on/off states.  My implementation only 1/2 works.  On initial display, the base state is active, regardless of the value in the DataContext.  When the data in the DataContext changes, the proper state is activated.

How do I get the proper state displayed on initial display of the listbox.

For security reasons I can not copy/paste XAML or View-Model code.

**Edit**: While I can't copy/paste the real code, the following skeleton hopefully reproduces the problem.

In a globally visible resource file:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyObjectItemTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      ... blend goodness ...
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>   
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The data context is passed into the data template by associating it with the ItemsTemplate attribute of the listbox in the main UI.

```
<ListBox ... ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyObjectItemTemplate}" .../>
```

Comment: Don't know much about DisplayStateBehaviors, but my first attempt at a quick fix would be to InvokePropertyChanged on the property the DataContext is bound to at a time where you know everything's going to be set up. If your DisplayStateBehavior is dependent at all on properties of the datacontext, and it's bound before that datacontext object is fully built, it won't have another opportunity to refresh itself until the datacontext changes again.

Comment: That was my plan for hacking around this, but it doesn't seem like it should be needed.  This feels like a symptom of me hooking things up wrong or using the wrong approach as this is, in my mind, a common use case.  If my approach is flawed, I'd rather "do it right, once".

Comment: This is hard to answer without the code.  I have questions like "what is a DisplayStateBehavior", "what is the shape of the DataContext", and "how is the DataContext supplied".  There are lots of opportunities to do something incorrect, but it's hard to see any possible misstep without the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue.  In the event it helps others, what I did to fix it was to extract out the guts of the DataTemplate into a UserControl.  This made everything work as I expected.  The DataTemplate still exists and is still involved, but it only has one element - the user control.  The visual states are all part of the user control.

In a globally visible resource file:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyObjectItemTemplate">
     <MyNamespace:MyUserControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In a separated file MyUserControl.cs

```
<UserControl ... x.Class="MyNamespace.MyUserControl" ...>
  <Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      ... blend goodness ...
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>   
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The data context is passed into the data template by associating it with the ItemsTemplate attribute of the listbox in the main UI.

```
<ListBox ... ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyObjectItemTemplate}" .../>
```

Comment: You might count your question as answered with your answer.

Comment: There is a 2 day wait period before I can do that.